# I am trying to attach a hover action, but the hover action is being called immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I am writing my first jQuery plugin.  I am trying add a hover action, but the hover response is being called immediately.  Here is my plugin:

```
(function($){
  var Help = function(element, options) {
    this.$element = element;
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.help.defaults, options);
  };

  Help.prototype.hover = function(name){
    alert(name);
  };

  $.fn.help = function(option){
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var help = $this.data('help');
      var options = "";
      var data = $this.data('help-id');
      if(!help) {
        $this.data('help', (help = new Help(this, options)));
      }
      $this.on('hover', help.hover(data));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

I attach my plugin with `$('#one').help()`, but this immediately calls the hover function.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing a function to `on` but the result of the call of your function.

Replace

```
$this.on('hover', help.hover(data));
```

with

```
$this.on('hover', function(){help.hover(data)});
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the help.  Will accept answer when SO will allow me to. (8 mins)